# Selecting first row from a group after order

Tags: hive, impala

Here is what my table looks like:

```
appl_db_srvr_xref_id  secrty_ctl_id assmt_dt  cmdb_id  secrty_ctl_elemnt_impmtn_cd
       180                 43       1/1/2018    227         N 
       180                 43       9/31/2018   227         Y
       179                 28       1/1/2018    710         N
       179                 29       2/2/2018    710         N
       179                 43       3/3/2018    710         N
```

What I need is to group by (appl_db_srvr_xref_id, secrty_ctl_id, and cmdb_id) sort by date, and return the most current row. So in this instance I would like to return:

```
180   43   227   Y
179   28   710   N
179   29   710   N
179   43   710   N
```

what I am trying is:

```
SELECT secrty_ctl_id, 
       appl_db_srvr_xref_id, 
       cmdb_id, 
       assmt_dt 
 FROM tablename 
 GROUP BY 
       secrty_ctl_id, 
       appl_db_srvr_xref_id, 
       cmdb_id 
 ORDER BY assmt_dt desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use row_number() analytic function:

```
select
       secrty_ctl_id, 
       appl_db_srvr_xref_id, 
       cmdb_id, 
       assmt_dt
from
(
SELECT secrty_ctl_id, 
       appl_db_srvr_xref_id, 
       cmdb_id, 
       assmt_dt,
       row_number() over (partition by appl_db_srvr_xref_id, secrty_ctl_id, cmdb_id order by assmt_dt desc) rn
 FROM tablename 
 )s
where rn=1;
```